# Prevent jailbroken/rooted devices from accessing MFP 7.1

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to understand how the MobileFirst Platform could prevent Jailbroken/rooted devices from accessing its resources.

- Does MobileFirst Platform provide this type of security.?
- How can we implement it as I could not find any resource to walk us through it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MobileFirst Platform Foundation does not, in itself, provide any facility to prevent jailbroken / rooted devices from accessing resources.  However, you can use MaaS360 or Trusteer to provide this kind of protection as desired.

There's a tech note [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27039422) that gives an overview of mobile OS features that can be used by various versions of MobileFirst Platform Foundation and Worklight.